# How to test a React hook used within a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I am trying to write an integration test for a hook `useMyHook` that is using multiple hooks connected to different contexts, and is also used in an `App` component. I want to test that the hook is making a certain API call.

This is how the test code looks like:

```
  const wrapper = (
  <Provider1>
    <Provider2>
      <App />
    <Provider2>
  </Provider1>
  );
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(), { wrapper });
  expect(typeof result.current.callApi).toBe("function");
  const callApi = jest.spyOn(result.current, "callApi");
  expect(callApi).toBeCalled();
```

The wrapper is a tree of providers together with the App component.

The problem I have right now is that `result.current` returns `null` at the moment, which suggests that the hook is never rendered. I don't quite understand why the hook isn't rendered.

Do you have any idea of how to write an integration test for this API call in a clean way?

Comment: so, it sounds like you just want a unit test here, why? because your api should already have its own test suite so you don't need to test it from your react app. that said you can add an E2E test with cypress or something that will hit a development/staging version of the API (or prod if your feeling brave). 

from the code you provided it's a but hard to tell whats going on as its so abstract also that line about testing the type of a return value it a bit funky but you want to import all the things it consumes (hooks / utils / etc...) and mock their return values in the test

Comment: part 2: once you've imported all the dependancies of the hook you can make a test suite with all the scenarios the hook will encounter. but yeah this is just a general reply as I can't really tell what would cause a null return vs what it should be returning without more context. but just wanted to note that you don't need to hit the API from your hook test (i would strongly recommend against it and leave it to an E2E test). what you're writing is a unit test and it only needs to concerned with its self

Comment: I'd recommend testing your hooks and testing your component that uses your hooks separately via unit tests. https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/ < this library is for testing react hooks.